# Find the stale roles in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there any way to analyze in snowflake, which roles has not been used for any query in snowflake in last one year?

The roles view in snowflake.account_usage has no such column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can query the query_history and the roles views of the snowflake.account_usage schema to get this list:

```
select name from snowflake.account_usage.roles where deleted_on is null
and name not in (
select distinct ROLE_NAME 
from snowflake.account_usage.query_history where start_time > current_date() - interval '1 year');
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/roles.html